# Passing Focus or Click to child EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, user-experience

I am trying to create a layout that consists of a Parent LinearLayout, A Child Relative Layout which holds the label TextView and Error TextView and another Child EditText.

When the Parent LinearLayout or the label is clicked I want the Child EditText to be focused. Thus far I have tried the following:

1. android:labelFor="@+id/account_number_input" in the parent layout
2. adding android:duplicateParentState="true" to the EditText and make the Parent LinearLayout focusable and clickable
3. Also tried android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" on the Parent LinearLayout while being focusable.

Nothing seems to achieve the desired effect.

Above is a sample code. I have multiple similar items which all need a custom label and an error section.

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/account_number_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            style="@style/EditTextLinearLayout">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/account_number_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/add_account_number_label"
                    android:labelFor="@+id/username_input"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/account_number_error"
                    style="@style/EditTextLabel"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/account_number_error"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/account_number_label"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    style="@style/EditTextError"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/account_number_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/add_account_number_hint"
                style="@style/EditTextInput"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please try adding android:focusableInTouchMode="true" into the parent LinearLayout.

Comment: Subrato M. I tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling `requestFocus()` on the view you need focus on `onClick()` event. 
Ex:

```
findViewById(R.id.yourParentViewId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    editText.requestFocus();
  }
});
```

Comment: This should work, however is there a way in which I can override the LinearLayout and add the functionality above, so that I wouldn't have to pair each LinearLayout to it's respective EditText?

Comment: You can add the onClick listener to the desired view(layout) and requestFocus() for edit text. Also, if you are asking for the list of items, then in your list's parent layout you need to follow the same solution.